# при создании контакта старый стирается, почему и оцените как я пишу код

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
# -*- coding in UTF-8 -*-
import pickle

class WriteListNomber:
    # Записываем в Список Контактов
    def __init__(self, name, namber):
        self.name = name
        self.namber = namber
        ListNameNam[ self.name ] = self.namber
        FileSeiv = open("SeiveInfo.data", "wb")
        pickle.dump(ListNameNam, FileSeiv)
        FileSeiv.close()

class printListNam:
    #Выводит на экран список контактов
    def __init__(self):
        FileSeiv = open("SeiveInfo.data", "rb")
        LoadingInfo = pickle.load(FileSeiv)
        print(LoadingInfo)
        FileSeiv.close()

# Список контактов
ListNameNam = {
               "ФИО": "Номер"
}

# Приветствие и выдача инструкций пользователю
print("Вас приветствует база мобильных номероа")
print("Введи 'Чтение контактов' для выведения на экран списка контактов")
print("Введи 'Сделать запись' для записи нового контакта")
print("Для завершения работы введи 0 ")

# Ввод команды пользователем
comandUser = input("---> ")

# Обработкка полученных команд от пользователя
while True:
    print("Выполнение команды")
    if comandUser == 'Чтение контактов':
        printListNam()
        comandUser = input("Введи новую команду \n ---> ")
    elif comandUser == 'Сделать запись':
        name = input("Введи имя \n --->")
        namber = input("Введи номер \n --->")
        WriteListNomber(name, namber)
        comandUser = input("Введи новую команду \n ---> ")
    elif comandUser == '0':
        print("Программа завершена")
        break
```

Comment: Код пишешь нормально (почти), а вот вопросы не очень. Я не понял в чем проблема и как ее воспроизвести.

Comment: когда добавляешь в словарь новый ключ, старый пропадает. Тоесть ввел я Иванов 891034 а затем Вован 89234 посте этого Иванов пропадает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не создаете экземпляр класса. У вас два отдельных класса, которые работают как функции. Собственно классы вами используются без понимания их смысла.

Нужно вот например так

```
class Abonent:
    def __init__(self, name, number):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number

class Notebook:
    def __init__(self):
        self.abonents = []
    def addAbonent(self, abonent):
        self.abonents.append(abonent)

    def saveToFile(self, filename):
        abonentsDict = {}
        for ab in self.abonents:
            abonentsDict[ab.name] = ab.number
        with open(fileame, 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(data, abonentsDict)
```

Использование

```
myAbonents = Notebook()
ivan = Abonent('Ivan','12345')
mary = Abonent('MAry','54321')
myAbonents.addAbonent(ivan)
myAbonents.addAbonent(mary)
myAbonents.saveToFile('notebook.data')
```

И файл вы открываете для записи, соответственно старое все стирается и заменяется новым.

Вот так очень очень плохо

```
while True:
```

вот пример

```
choose = -1
while (choose != 3):
    print("[1] - MenuItem1")
    print("[2] - MenuItem1")
    print("[3] - Exit")
    choose = int(input("Выбор= "))
    if choose == 1:
        ...
    if choose == 2:
        ...
```

Comment: Да! 4 SPACE ))))

Comment: проблема не решина  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\verto\Documents\Python_test\Список_номеров(StackOverflow).py", line 22, in <module>
    myAbonents.addAbonent(ivan)
  File "C:\Users\verto\Documents\Python_test\Список_номеров(StackOverflow).py", line 10, in addAbonent
    self.abonents.add(abonent)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'add'

Comment: Там опечатка. Не add а append. В сообщении об ошибке об этом явно написано.

Comment: @LordDaedra. вы же разумно понимаете, что это не весь код написанный за вас, а направление в котором надо двигаться.

Comment: сложная штука это программирование, уже месяц 3 учу его и до сих пор не знаю стандартных модулей. я учу самостоятельно (без знаний английского) мне трудно понять эти ошибки

Comment: @LordDaedra. вы не знаете принципов программирования и стандартных алгоритмов, поэтому пытаетесь придумать все решения сами - это не работающая стратегия. Начните с изучения литературы: Вирт "Алгоритмы и структуры данных", Петцольд "Код - тайный язык информатики".